# How can create a new contact in Contact in windows phone 8.1 uinversal app

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Is there a way to create a new contact in windows phone 8.1 universal app? currently contact store only supports find a contact by id or get all contacts from contact store?

Comment: For Windows Phone you [create your own `ContactStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631244) for your app. You can then add Contacts to this store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! found the solution after some search. App can create their own contact store which appear in Windows Phone people app. All you need the following code to add contact....

```
using Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation;

 public async void CreateContact()
    {

        var contactStore = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync(ContactStoreSystemAccessMode.ReadWrite,ContactStoreApplicationAccessMode.LimitedReadOnly);
        var createContactQuery = contactStore.CreateContactQuery();

        ContactInformation ci = new ContactInformation();
        ci.DisplayName ="Muhammad saifullah";

      ///Save Thumbnail image.
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var data = await client.GetInputStreamAsync(new Uri("imageurlhere"));
        await ci.SetDisplayPictureAsync(data);

        StoredContact sc = new StoredContact(contactStore, ci);
        IDictionary<string, object> props = await sc.GetPropertiesAsync();
        props.Add(KnownContactProperties.Email, "myemail@domcin.com");
        props.Add(KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone, "+1000000101001");
        props.Add(KnownContactProperties.JobTitle, "---");


        await sc.SaveAsync();           

    }
```