# How to add a phone number to a StoredContact in App's ContactStore in Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a ContactStore for my app and want to store a phone number to it. I am able to set the display name but to add phone number you have to create a custom property which does not show up in contact details in the people hub. How do I add this detail as a valid phone number that actually shows up in the people hub?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation.ContactStore contactStore = await Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation.ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync();
        StoredContact newContact = new StoredContact(contactStore);
        newContact.RemoteId = data.Id;
        newContact.GivenName = data.CodeProvider + " " + data.CodeDescription;

        IDictionary<string, object> extendedProps = await newContact.GetExtendedPropertiesAsync();
        extendedProps.Add("phone", data.CodeValue.ToString());

        await newContact.SaveAsync();
```

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer. It can be done using `KnownContactProperties`.
Details here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527801/how-can-create-a-new-contact-in-contact-in-windows-phone-8-1-uinversal-app)